# transpose formula when x is power of n

Tags: transpose

I need help transposing this formula to solve for F0. the problem is that i don't know what to do when Octave is > 2. Apologies if this is a noob question :P

$S_n$ = $\dfrac{F0-2^{Octave} \times 20}{(2^{Octave} \times 20)/12}$

Comment: So what is your question?  What formula?

Comment: hi, there's a link to the image

Comment: Why not first divide 20 by 12 in the denominator?

Answer (score 0):

$F_0 = 2^{Oct} \left( 5/3 + 20 \right)$.

Comment: thank you for your answer, however, I tried it out but the results dont match. f0 should be 440 and i got 346. When Octave = 4, MusicScale = 5. In your answer MusicScale, lets call it Sn, is neglected, i think it should be present

Answer (score 0):

And as always.. It was easier than i thought.

My mistake was in the order of operations, using python shell here, so i missed some parentheses. Anyways, the answer is:

$F_0 = S_n \left((2^{Oct} \cdot 20)/12\right) + \left( 2^{Oct} \cdot 20 \right)$.

where $S_n$ is the Music scale and $Oct$ is the octave